# What do you call a script that initiates other scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

Simple question - I have a shell script that initiates other subscripts as its only major function. Is there any industry standard / best practice name for this type of script?

Comment: Not clear, did you click on post before writing it completely, if yes then kindly edit it with full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call this a wrapper script, perhaps?
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html